# regarding lasso.score in lasso modeling using scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining, lasso

I once saw the following code segment of using lasso model based on scikit-learn

```
lasso = LassoCV(normalize = True, max_iter=2000)
lasso.fit(X_train, y_train);
lasso.score(X_test, y_test)

y_pred = lasso.predict(X_test)
```

I can understand `lasso.fit` and `lasso_predict`, but what does `lasso.score` generally offer? According to the `scikit-learn`, it `Returns the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction`. I am not quite clear how to use this kind of information?

Answer (score 1):

R^2 is a statistical measure of how close the data are to the fitted regression line. It does this by seeing percentage of the variance of dependent varible that's explained by independent variable.

To know more about R^2 score refer this [video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-statistics/bivariate-data-ap/assessing-fit-least-squares-regression/v/r-squared-or-coefficient-of-determination).

So, basically it is a metric to see how well model fits the data but it is not adequate.

Refer this [discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350484/why-is-r-squared-not-a-good-measure-for-regressions-fit-using-lasso) on why R^2 score is not good for Lasso.